# How to inject my application class for Room

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm really confused about dagger 2. There are so many different ways people provide a solution. How can i inject my application to provide my database?

I already have my database module, an application module that provide my application. my applicationComponent with a builder inside it (have no idea what it does). With that builder it is not possible to build it inside my application class!?

Application class:

```
public class OnSiteApplication extends Application implements HasActivityInjector {
    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> dispatchingAndroidInjector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
}
```

AppComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class, AndroidInjectionModule.class})
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<OnSiteApplication> {

    @Component.Builder
     interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);

        AppComponent build();
    }

    void inject(OnSiteApplication onSiteApplication);
}
```

Application Module:

```
@Module(includes = DatabaseModule.class)
public class ApplicationModule {
    private static final String SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME = "OnSitePreferences";

    private final OnSiteApplication application;

    public ApplicationModule(OnSiteApplication appContext) {
        this.application = appContext;
    }

    @Provides
    public OnSiteApplication provideOnSiteApplication() {
        return application;
    }
}
```

Database Module:

```
@Module
public class DatabaseModule {
    @Provides
    public static OnSiteDatabase provideDatabase(Application appContext) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(appContext,
                OnSiteDatabase.class, OnSiteDatabase.DATABASE_NAME)
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    public static ProjectDao provideProjectAccess(OnSiteDatabase onSiteDatabase) {
        return onSiteDatabase.projectDao();
    }

}
```

Most of the solution are one year or older. What is the most modern way of injecting OS based classes like Application?

Comment: @i-van-de-poll, aren't  your problem solve yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your implementation there are some problems:

**Problem - 1:** 
You provide `DatabaseModule` as dependency to `ApplicationModule` which is not correct as DatabaseModule never used inside ApplicationModule. Rather you can pass 
ApplicationModule to DatabaseModule as application context is used to create database. [**But which is not required, check below**]

**Problem - 2:** 
Here `ApplicationModule` is useless as `Application` is already provided through `@BindsInstance`. So you can delete `ApplicationModule` from here.

So final implementation looks like:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {DatabaseModule.class, AndroidInjectionModule.class})
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<OnSiteApplication> {

    @Component.Builder
     interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);

        AppComponent build();
    }

    void inject(OnSiteApplication onSiteApplication);
}
```

And `OnSiteApplication`, Create the `AppComponent` like below:

```
public class OnSiteApplication extends Application implements HasActivityInjector {
    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> dispatchingAndroidInjector;

    AppComponent appComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build();
    }

    public AppComponent getAppComponent() {
        return appComponent;
    }

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
}
```